# Why does the printwriter split my message into two strings?

Tags: java, string, io

I am trying to create a java program to cause a buffer overflow in the program [Vulnserver](http://grey-corner.blogspot.com/2010/12/introducing-vulnserver.html).

Whenever I send a string with more than 4094 characters, it receives the command the command as two string.  It splits it again into three strings at 8188 characters etc.

Why does it do this? And how do I stop it?  I am trying to send the command TRUN followed by 5000 A's.  It is not the recieveing program as it works with a perl program.

```
 package fuzzer;

 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import java.net.Socket;
 import java.util.Scanner;


 public class VulnserverFuzz {

public static Socket s;
private static String Command = "TRUN ";//Command TRUN

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{


    PrintWriter pri = null;
    try {
        s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999);
        pri = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);

    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    (new Thread(new VulnThread())).start();//Starts thread to listen for response

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int k=0; k<5000; ++k){Command += "A";}// Add 5099 A's to Command


    String bre = (Command);
    pri.println(bre);

    pri.flush();

  }
 }
```

Response:
TRUN Completed 
Unknown Command

Comment: Not sure if it makes much difference, but it looks like you are starting the Server Thread after the Client. (VulnThread()).start();  What happens if you put it before the socket connection?

Comment: Sorry don't think my edit saved before. The vulnthread gets the response from the server from a scanner.  Vulneserver is a separate executable.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read the manual - but I think the response you got from the server is that of a single command.

You ran `TRUN AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...` - so it tried to run the command `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA...`.

The response is:
`TRUN Completed` - Indicates it ran the `TRUN` command.
`Unknown Command` - Indicates that the command specified as an argument (`AAAAAAAAAA...`) is unknown.

There is no reason why your code should split the request.

Try sending the command `TRUN AAA` to verify - you should get the same output.